# Adding text field to attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, fields-attributes

[image]

I am trying to add a text field to my attribute table in ArcMap, but every time I do it adds a string type field instead.I've tried turning off the Allow Null Values and shortening the Length, but no matter what it makes it string instead of text field. If I can't make it a text field, how do I fill in the records for a string field? The table is attached to a polygon layer, I'm trying to add in short character codes to ID each polygon.

Why is it doing this and how do I get around it?

Comment: A string type is a text field.  If you're looking to add a CLOB (character large object) text field to shapefile, that will fail, since shapefile doesn't support CLOB (and is limited to 254 characters). If you [Edit] the question to provide more details about your table format, you can get more specific assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string field is a text field! Also you cannot have a space in the field name, that is allowable in the alias.

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected behavior in ArcMap.

String is common for programmers, and text is a more easier way of putting it in for new users to understand.

[Field](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/field.htm)

[image]